# Zend framework 1.11 Gdata Spreadsheets insertRow very slow

Tags: zend-framework, google-docs

I'm using insertRow to populate an empty spreadsheet, it starts off taking about 1 second to insert a row and then slows down to around 5 seconds after 150 rows or so.

Has anyone experienced this kind of behaviour?
There aren't any calculations on the data in the spreadsheet that could be getting longer with more data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to be strict.

If you take a look at class "Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets" you figure that the method insertRow() is written in a very not optimal way. See:

```
public function insertRow($rowData, $key, $wkshtId = 'default')
{
    $newEntry = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListEntry();
    $newCustomArr = array();
    foreach ($rowData as $k => $v) {
        $newCustom = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_Extension_Custom();
        $newCustom->setText($v)->setColumnName($k);
        $newEntry->addCustom($newCustom);
    }

    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery();
    $query->setSpreadsheetKey($key);
    $query->setWorksheetId($wkshtId);

    $feed = $this->getListFeed($query);
    $editLink = $feed->getLink('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post');

    return $this->insertEntry($newEntry->saveXML(), $editLink->href, 'Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListEntry');
}
```

In short, it loads your whole spreadsheet just in order to learn this value $editLink->href in order to post new row into your spreadsheet.

The cure is to avoid using this method insertRow.
Instead, get your $editLink->href once in your code and then insert new rows each time by reproducing the rest of behaviour of this method. I.e, in your code instead of $service->insertRow() use following:

```
//get your $editLink once:
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($key);
$query->setWorksheetId($wkshtId);
$query->setMaxResults(1);

$feed = $service->getListFeed($query);
$editLink = $feed->getLink('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post');
....
//instead of $service->insertRow:
$newEntry = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListEntry();
$newCustomArr = array();
foreach ($rowData as $k => $v) {
    $newCustom = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_Extension_Custom();
    $newCustom->setText($v)->setColumnName($k);
    $newEntry->addCustom($newCustom);
}
$service->insertEntry($newEntry->saveXML(), $editLink->href, 'Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListEntry');
```

Don't forget to encourage this great answer, it costed me few days to figure out. I think ZF is great however sometimes you dont want to rely on their coode too much when it comes to resources optimization.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I added `$query->setMaxResults(1);` right below `$query->setWorksheetId($wkshtId);` and added static function variable to cache `$editLink` so it's retrieved only once.

Comment: @Ralphz cool, I updated the answer, thanks. Nice catch, gonna be extremely useful for those who have to deal with huge sheets